# On Linux, is access() faster than stat()?

Tags: linux, performance, file, posix, stat

I would have assumed that access() was just a wrapper around stat(), but I've been googling around and have [found some anecdotes](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2009-November/msg00403.html) about replacing stat calls with 'cheaper' access calls. Assuming you are only interested in checking if a file exists, is access faster? Does it completely vary by filesystem?

Comment: it seems to be rather a wrapper around open().  it does make sense to me that it would be faster and it's nice that it's setuid aware.  I'd love to see some benchmarks though.

Comment: `access` is in man section 2, so I'm assuming it's its own system call instead of being a libc wrapper around something (so, in theory, it could be faster than stat, etc)

Comment: The important thing isn't performance, but semantics. `access()` tells you you can read/write/execute a thing, even after any access-control plugins (ie. SELinux) or other components (extended ACLs; AFS permissions; etc) have been involved. `stat()` tells you the traditional-UNIX file permissions, but they may or may not be the whole story. And because `access()` is [potentially] doing more work, I'd actually expect it to be slower.

Comment: I suppose it is very dependant. Related example: on my PC `fstat()` is 2x faster than `pread()`. However, on one low-RAM box with MIPS cpu, `fstat()` is 1.5x *slower* than `pread()`. So the message of this comment is that you should always *measure* to get concrete times for your environment.

Answer (score 10):

#### Theory

I doubt that.

In lower layers of kernel there is no much difference between `access()` and `stat()` calls both are performing *lookup operation*: they map file name to an entry in *dentry cache* and to *inode* (it is actual kernel structure, `inode`). Lookup is slow operation because you need to perform it for each part of path, i.e. for `/usr/bin/cat` you will need to lookup `usr`, `bin` and then `cat` and it can require reading from disk -- that is why inodes and dentries are cached in memory.

Major difference between that calls is that `stat()` performs conversion of `inode` structure to `stat` structure, while `access()` will do a simple check, but that time is small comparing with *lookup* time.

The real performance gain can be achieved with *at*-operations like `faccessat()` and `fstatat()`, which allow to `open()` directory once, just compare:

```
struct stat s;
stat("/usr/bin/cat", &s);   // lookups usr, bin and cat = 3
stat("/usr/bin/less", &s);  // lookups usr, bin and less = 3

int fd = open("/usr/bin");  // lookups usr, bin = 2
fstatat(fd, "cat", &s);     // lookups cat = 1
fstatat(fd, "less", &s);    // lookups less = 1
```

#### Experiments

I wrote a small python script which calls `stat()` and `access()`:

```
import os, time, random
files = ['gzexe', 'catchsegv', 'gtroff', 'gencat', 'neqn', 'gzip', 
        'getent', 'sdiff', 'zcat', 'iconv', 'not_exists', 'ldd', 
        'unxz', 'zcmp', 'locale', 'xz', 'zdiff', 'localedef', 'xzcat']
access = lambda fn: os.access(fn, os.R_OK)

for i in xrange(1, 80000): 
    try:
        random.choice((access, os.stat))("/usr/bin/" + random.choice(files))
    except:
        continue
```

I traced system with SystemTap to measure time spent in different operations. Both `stat()` and `access()` system calls use `user_path_at_empty()` kernel function which represents lookup operation:

```
stap -ve ' global tm, times, path;
probe lookup = kernel.function("user_path_at_empty") 
    { name = "lookup"; pathname = user_string_quoted($name); }
probe lookup.return = kernel.function("user_path_at_empty").return 
    { name = "lookup"; }
probe stat = syscall.stat 
    { pathname = filename; }
probe stat, syscall.access, lookup
        { if(pid() == target() && isinstr(pathname, "/usr/bin")) {
        tm[name] = local_clock_ns(); } }
probe syscall.stat.return, syscall.access.return, lookup.return
        { if(pid() == target() && tm[name]) {
        times[name] <<< local_clock_ns() - tm[name];
        delete tm[name];
        } }
    ' -c 'python stat-access.py'
```

Here are the results:

```
         COUNT      AVG
lookup   80018    1.67 us
stat     40106    3.92 us
access   39903    4.27 us
```

Note that I disabled SELinux in my experiments, as it adds significant influence on the results.

Comment: You're measuring the cached case.  It's possible that `stat` has to check some things that `access` doesn't, like the block count.  Most filesystems probably store a block count in the inode, rather than having to walk the blockmap B-tree, because stat-every-file in a dir is a very common operation that they need to optimize for.  Given that, everything needed to answer a `stat` query probably comes from one disk seek to read the inode.

Comment: Please do not blindly trust this advice. I tested it in my machine and the performance of stat and faccessat seems completely equivalent.

Comment: @Siscia how your did you perform your experiment? Without more information, it is hard to tell, what factors come to play.